# Observe Vue.js store boolean change inside component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a vue.js store that holds a boolean value and I need to detect when this changes inside a component. When userEnabled changes I need to call a method inside the component. I don't need to compute a new value.

My question is should I be using **'watch'** for this or is there a more efficient way? If so, should I be configuring the watch inside 'mounted' and what about unwatch?

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state : {
        userEnabled: false,
    }
});
```

**user.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="user"></div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        watch: {
            'this.$store.userEnabled': function() {
                console.log('test');
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.$store.watch( state => state.userEnabled, (newValue, oldValue) => {
                // call function!
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the functionality is to be executed only inside the component, `watch` is the way to go. You might map `userEnabled` to a computed prop of the component to improve readability, but that's optional.

Manually calling `$store.watch` in `mounted` mainly gives you the option to store the returned unwatch function and stop watching the property at an arbitrary point. However, if you want to watch the property as long as the component exists anyway, this adds no benefits.

Finally, if the desired functionality should be run whenever `userEnabled` is changed, regardless of specific components handling the change, a better approach might be to move that code into the Vuex mutation function which changes the value of `userEnabled` in the store.

Comment: Yea the functionality will only apply to User.vue. My thought process led me away from computed because I’m not actually computing a new value but simply calling a function. Computed property felt like the wrong choice?

Comment: Yes, in this case I also think `watch` is the best way to implement your desired behavior. As I wrote, you still can wrap the store property into a computed prop of the component to make using it easier, but that's purely an aesthetic decision.